# Logging in to eBay using HttpWebRequest fails due to 'The browser you are using is rejecting cookies' response

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, cookiecontainer

I'm trying to log in to my eBay account using the following code:

```
string signInURL = "https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?co_partnerid=2&siteid=0&UsingSSL=1";
string postData = String.Format("MfcISAPICommand=SignInWelcome&userid={0}&pass={1}", "username", "password");
string contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string method = "POST";
string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)";

CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(signInURL);
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
req.Method = method;
req.ContentType = contentType;
req.UserAgent = userAgent;
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] loginDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
req.ContentLength = loginDataBytes.Length;
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(loginDataBytes, 0, loginDataBytes.Length);
stream.Close();
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader xsr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
String responseText = xsr.ReadToEnd();
```

Obviously substituting my real username and password. When I look at the string `responseText`, I see that part of the response from eBay is

> The browser you are using is rejecting cookies.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

P.S.  And yes, I am also using the eBay API, but this is for something slightly different than what I want to do with the API.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a direct http request. The Ebay site has functionality to talk to a browser (probably to store the session cookie). Unless you make the request code smart enough to use cookies correctly it won't work. You'll probably have to use the internet explorer object instead.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing the POST you need to download the page with the form that you are submitting in your code, take the cookie they give you, put it in your `CookieContainer` (making sure you get the path right) and post it back up in your request.

To clarify, while you might be POSTing the correct data, you are not sending the cookie that needs to go with it. You will get this cookie from the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept the http traffic to see what exactly what had happened. I use Fiddler2. It is the good tools for debugging http. So I can know whos wrong, my application or the remote web server.

Using fiddler, you can see the request header, response header with its cookies as well as response content. It used in the middle of your app and the Ebay.

Based on my experience. I think it is because Ebay cookie sent to you is not send back to Ebay server. Fiddler will prove it whether yes or not.

Another thing, the response cookie you receive should be send back to next request by using the same CookieContainer.

You should notice that CookieContainer has a bug on .Add(Cookie) and .GetCookies(uri) method. You may not using it, but internal codes might use it.

See the details and fix here:

http://dot-net-expertise.blogspot.com/2009/10/cookiecontainer-domain-handling-bug-fix.html

CallMeLaNN